# Issue with WMIC and 'and' verb

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm having a little trouble getting this WMIC query to work.

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :wmic nicconfig where IPEnabled=TRUE and DefaultIPgateway is not null get ipaddress,macaddress,defaultipgateway /format:list
exit /b

:wmic
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"wmic %*"') do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
exit /b
```

I'm missing something simple but I don't know what. I keep getting "and - Invalid alias verb."

TIA

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bill_Stewart points out, the DefaultIPGateway column holds an array datatype, which can't be queried with WQL.  That doesn't mean `wmic` is incapable of handling compound `where` clauses, though.  You simply have to enclose the argument to `where` within quotation marks.

```js
wmic nicconfig where "IPEnabled=TRUE and IPConnectionMetric>0" get ipaddress,macaddress,defaultipgateway /format:list
```

See?  That whole `IPEnabled=TRUE and IPConnectionMetric>0` thing is one argument.  You're getting an error because `AND` is occurring where wmic expects `get` or `list` or `call`, etc.

Incidentally, if you ever need to query a string, you must use single quotes within the double quotes.  Unlike booleans and ints, strings must be quoted.

```js
wmic nicconfig where "Description LIKE '%%NVIDIA%%'" list /format:list
```

---

There are a couple of other issues to consider.  When calling `wmic` within a `for` loop, equal signs and commas either need to be quoted or caret-escaped.  Also, in a `for /f` loop, you don't need both single and double quotes surrounding the entire command.  Change your script as follows and it should work:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

call :wmic nicconfig where "IPEnabled=TRUE and IPConnectionMetric>0" get ipaddress^^,macaddress^^,defaultipgateway /format:list
exit /b

:wmic
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic %*') do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
exit /b
```

Comment: When I run this, I just get `> was unexpected at this time` I have tried to escape it using `^>` but that didn't help either.

Comment: It works from the cmd console.  Could be because you're doing `call :wmic`.  Oh well.  You can also do `IPConnectionMetric!=''` and it'll return the same results.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It's filtering out the `=` sign. Escaping or doubling it does nothing. I need to get it working in a for loop somehow or another. If I have to do it 2x that's not a problem.

Comment: Ahh Ha! That is the one thing I didn't try. Stupid commas! Thanks again Rojo!

Answer (score 2):

WQL does not support querying array data types (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902.aspx). This will be annoying to accomplish in shell script (batch), but it's pretty straightforward in PowerShell:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" |
  where-object { $_.DefaultIPGateway }
```

Comment: Helpful link is helpful.  And I'm glad you've started posting full solutions as answers, rather than unfulfilled comments to "use Powershell" without explanation.  +1

Comment: "Use PowerShell" is a good idea in general. Cmd.exe shell script (batch) is far inferior in nearly every conceivable way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bill. I used to use Powershell when I was the admin in a win7 env but unfortunately, this new contract position still has WinXP Pro and it's sans powershell. :(  We're in the final stages of testing Win7 for compatibility, so I'll have it soon.

Comment: You can install PowerShell 2.0 on Windows XP and Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very same question at work. My attempt was using VBS and making IpEnabled part of the query, and DefaultIPGateway part of a Sub, thanks in part to how the sample code is formatted by WMICreator Tool.

This should only write out valid values when both apply:

```
    strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled=True",,48) 

For Each objItem in colItems 
DoWork
next

Sub DoWork()
    If isNull(objItem.DefaultIPGateway) Then
exit sub
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "DefaultIPGateway: " & Join(objItem.DefaultIPGateway, ",")
    End If
    Wscript.Echo "DHCPServer: " & objItem.DHCPServer
    Wscript.Echo "DNSDomain: " & objItem.DNSDomain
    Wscript.Echo "DNSHostName: " & objItem.DNSHostName
    If isNull(objItem.IPAddress) Then
        Wscript.Echo "IPAddress: "
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "IPAddress: " & Join(objItem.IPAddress, ",")
    End If
    Wscript.Echo "IPConnectionMetric: " & objItem.IPConnectionMetric
    Wscript.Echo "IPEnabled: " & objItem.IPEnabled
    If isNull(objItem.IPSubnet) Then
        Wscript.Echo "IPSubnet: "
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "IPSubnet: " & Join(objItem.IPSubnet, ",")
    End If
end Sub
```